# Validar edad mínima y máxima JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando validar la edad máxima y mínima del usuario, necesito que dada la fecha de nacimiento en el formato `yyy-mm-dd` pueda saber la edad, pero si la edad es menor a 6 meses y mayor a 70 años no me deje continuar con el siguiente paso...

```js
function calcularEdad(fecha) {
  console.log(fecha);
  var hoy = new Date();
  var cumpleanos = new Date(fecha);
  var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleanos.getFullYear();
  var mes = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleanos.getMonth();

  if (mes < 0 || (mes === 0 && hoy.getDate() < cumpleanos.getDate())) {
    edad--;
  }

  // Restamos 6 meses
  hoy.setMonth(hoy.getMonth() - 6)

  // Fecha actual menos 6 meses
  var menosSeis = hoy.getFullYear() + "-" + (hoy.getMonth() - 1) + "-" + hoy.getDate();

 console.log(menosSeis);
  
 var fechados = new Date(menosSeis);
 var resultado = cumpleanos.getTime() > fechados.getTime();
  
  if(resultado)
    {
      console.log('Tiene mas de 6 meses y menos de 70 años');
    } else {
      console.log('tiene menos de 6 meses');
    }
 
  return edad;
}

edadExacta = calcularEdad('2020-11-30');

if (edadExacta.mes <= 6) {
      alert("Edad mínima no válida.");
    } else if (edadExacta.anio > 69) {
      alert("No puede superar los 70 años de edad.");
    }
```

En resumen es esto lo que quiero lograr:

Si edad es menor a 6 meses : "tienes menos de 6 meses, no puedes continuar".
si la edad es mayor a 70 años: "Tienes mas de 70 años, no puedes continuar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no estás calculando la edad, simplemente, verificando que la fecha proporcionada esté dentro de un rango permitido. Hay que crear 4 objetos de fecha, todas con la fecha actual, excepto la que se va a verificar:

1. cumpleanos: Se aplica la fecha proporcionada por parámetro
2. hoy: Sin parámetros y no se modifica
3. menos6: Se restan 6 meses, que es el valor mínimo permitido
4. menos70: Se restan 70 años, que es el valor máximo permitido

Las operaciones son bastante sencillas al tener el objeto de fecha, simplemente usas `.setMonth()` y proporcionas parámetros: mes de la fecha actual, menos 6. O `.setYear()` con año de la fecha actual menos 70.

Sugiero devolver un valor tipo `resultado` con 3 opciones:
- -1: La fecha es menor de 6 meses
- 0: La fecha está dentro del rango permitido
- 1: La fecha es mayor a 70 años

```js
function calcularEdad(fecha) {
  var cumpleanos = new Date(fecha);
  var hoy = new Date();
  var menos6 = new Date();
  menos6.setMonth(hoy.getMonth() - 6);
  var menos70 = new Date();
  menos70.setYear(hoy.getYear() - 70);

  if(cumpleanos > menos6) {
      return -1; // Menor que 6 meses
  } else if(cumpleanos < menos70) {
      return 1; // Mayor que 70
  }
  return 0; // Está bien la fecha
}

console.log(calcularEdad('2019-12-30')); // Menor de 6 meses
console.log(calcularEdad('1949-11-30')); // Mayor 70 años
console.log(calcularEdad('1970-01-20')); // Ok

var prueba = calcularEdad('1949-11-30');
if(prueba == -1) {
    console.log('Menor de 6 meses');
} else if(prueba == 1) {
    console.log('Mayor de 70 años');
} else {
    console.log('Fecha correcta');
}
```